# OneTimeSetup Failed Nsubstitute for Entity Framework and NUnit Test

Tags: nunit, entity, nsubstitute

I'm trying to create unit test for a project, which uses entity framework with (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity included). I create the substitute for my dbContext like this:

```
        var applicationDbContext = Substitute.For<ApplicationDbContext>();

        var deviceTypeActionRulesMockSet = Substitute.For<DbSet<DeviceTypeActionRules>, IQueryable<DeviceTypeActionRules>>();
        var deviceTypeActionRulesData = new List<DeviceTypeActionRules>
        {
                new DeviceTypeActionRules() { ActionId = "CheckIn", DeviceTypeId = 1, Frequency = 60 },
                new DeviceTypeActionRules() { ActionId = "Turn On", DeviceTypeId = 2, Frequency = 20 },
                new DeviceTypeActionRules() { ActionId = "Turn Off", DeviceTypeId = 2, Frequency = 30 }
        }.AsQueryable();

        ((IQueryable<DeviceTypeActionRules>)deviceTypeActionRulesMockSet).Provider.Returns(deviceTypeActionRulesData.Provider);
        ((IQueryable<DeviceTypeActionRules>)deviceTypeActionRulesMockSet).Expression.Returns(deviceTypeActionRulesData.Expression);
        ((IQueryable<DeviceTypeActionRules>)deviceTypeActionRulesMockSet).ElementType.Returns(deviceTypeActionRulesData.ElementType);
        ((IQueryable<DeviceTypeActionRules>)deviceTypeActionRulesMockSet).GetEnumerator().Returns(deviceTypeActionRulesData.GetEnumerator());

        applicationDbContext.DeviceTypeActionRules.Returns(deviceTypeActionRulesMockSet);
```

The error occurs when I hit the last line in the code above, I get the following error:

Result Message: 
OneTimeSetUp: System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException : One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Castle.Proxies.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Castle.Proxies.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.

Comment: Not related, but instead of manually mocking `DbContext` use "InMemory" provider, which will provide more IQueryble experience for sql data. [Testing with InMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory).

Answer (score 0):

Inside my ApplicationDbContext, I changed the properties to be virtual:

```
public virtual DbSet<DeviceTypeActionRules> DeviceTypeActionRules { get; set; }
```

and that seemed to fix the issue shown above.